# When I'm trying to set a value for a base class from a child class (inheritance) it does not work (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an enemy (from EnemyCreator1 class) with both EnemyMove1 and MarkusEnemy scripts (EnemyMove1 is a parent class to MarkusEnemy class). In EnemyCreator1 class I set value mainState of the script EnemyMove1 to "CHASE", but when I'm trying to access it from that class it says that mainState is "IDLE" (Please read my coments below because there are more explanations about what am I trying to achieve)

```
    public class EnemyMove1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public enum mainStates { IDLE, CHASE }
        public mainStates mainState;
    
        void Update()
        {
            Debug.Log(mainState); //mainstate == IDLE, but should be CHASE
        }
    }
    
    public class EnemyCreator1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private GameObject enemyPrefab;
        public void CreateEnemyAndSetItsStateToChase()
        {
            GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab);
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove1>().mainState = EnemyMove1.mainStates.CHASE;
        }
    }
    public class MarkusEnemy : EnemyMove1
    {
        void Update()
        {
            EnemyMove enemyMoveScript = GetComponent<EnemyMove>();
            Debug.Log(enemyMoveScript.mainState); //mainstate == CHASE
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why using `GetComponent` if you already inherit from the type -> `MarkusEnemy` already **is** the `EnemyMove1` itself! Besides that is it possible that this is a typo? You are using `EnemyMove` but inherit from `EnemyMove1` ...

Comment: Its very hard to understand your design pattern. My simple guess is you are changing mainState of difference object and trying to check the mainState of another object. Looks like in `EnemyCreator1` you are `Instantiate` new GameObject of enemy? but this new object is not being referenced anywhere for you to access later

Comment: You are currently never setting the mainstate to CHASE at least I don't see you calling the ```CreateEnemyAndSetItsStateToChase()``` method. But the moment you do that which changes it's state it should also affect and print the different state now in the ```MarkusEnemy``` child class.

Comment: This is a very simplified version of the code, maybe oversimplified. I just want to know if it is possible to set some variable directly in the parent class on my object if it is also have a child class that inherits parent class (two classes on the same object), because I have some methods on my parent class that require variable from that parent class. I will give an example: on my parent class I have a method CheckState(); that has if(state == IDLE) //do some actions,   but how can I change state on that parent class outside the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping me, after searching for the information about base classes I decided that it is impossible to access directly it's variables from another objects' scripts so I just simply call methods with variables as arguments (I put variables in round brackets of the method)

Comment: `I decided that it is impossible to access directly it's variables from another objects' scripts` ... where did you get this information from? ^^ If your fields are `public` you can access it from anywhere ... in the inherited class itself you can access them anyway (if they are protected or public) since the inherited type already **has** the inherited fields ...

Comment: @derHugo yeah, it seems logical but it does not work, surprisingly. Even if I try to do this action - 'Debug.Log(enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove>())' the console will say "MarkusEnemy" but not "EnemyMove" so I cannot access its variables even if there are protected or public.

Comment: Because your enemy **has** the component `MarkusEnemy` which derives from `EnemyMove`! The same goes e.g. for `GetComponent<Renderer>()` which can return `SpriteRenderer` or `MeshRenderer` .. but you still can access `Renderer.material` which belongs to the common parent class ....

Comment: @derHugo I understand that but what can I do to change the value in EnemyMove outside the enemy gameobject? I have a method in EnemyMove which includes checking the value (mainState) like this - if(mainState == States.IDLE) //do something but when I try change value in EnemyMove outside the object like this - EnemyMove enemymove = enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove>() then enemymove.mainState = EnemyMove.States.IDLE it only changes the value in MarkusEnemy, but not in EnemyMove. I need to check it in EnemyMove because I have a lot of different enemies which have their on scripts, based on EnemyMove

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it looks like you are inheriting from a different base class EnemyMove, not EnemyMove1.

Comment: I've just fixed it, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Egor You sure about that? Did you clear the Debug window and try again? Nothing here seems wrong after that, assuming the GameObject EnemyMove1 is indeed only being instantiated from EnemyCreator1 script. Do you also have this gameobject also in the scene or being instantiated from another script?

Comment: @SpicyCatGames I have an object called "enemy" it has two scripts: EnemyMove and MarkusEnemy (MarkusEnemy Inherits from EnemyMove) When I try to modify value "mainState" on EnemyMove it modifies value on MarkusEnemy, but I need to modify it on EnemyMove because I have methods that require this variable (mainState) By the way I use enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove>().mainState = EnemyMove.mainState.CHASE on another object (enemyCreator)